# Is there a package in Rstudio that allows building a multiverse recommender system?

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

For my thesis, I am trying to create a Context-Aware Recommender System (CARS) in R. I have come across multiple packages such as ‘recosystem’ and 'recommenderlab' but I cannot find anything related to adding context variables directly to the recommender system. I am aware of pre- and post-filtering data by using contextual variables, but that is not an option for me.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update 13-07-2020**

I found a package on gitbub: https://github.com/andland/libFMexe
This is a R wrapper for the libFM software implementation for factorization machines. It can be used for CARS by adding the context variables as features. I will be experimenting with it this week.